# Layout changes is not showing after running the application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

The problem started when i deleted a **picture** from a `layout`, then i started the application on the mobile, but it seems the application still showing the **`old layout`** with the **picture**, i tried several solutions without any result.

I tired to change my java code, and the changes were applied correctly, but any change in the layout is not showing in the application.

this is the java file:

```
public class Jan extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#c99e67"));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);


    setTitle("paltoday");


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feb);
    CalendarView calendarView=(CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2016);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar cal2=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.set(Calendar.DATE,31);
    cal2.set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
    cal2.set(Calendar.YEAR,2016);
    cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);
    cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    long millis2 = cal2.getTimeInMillis();
    calendarView.setMinDate(millis);
    calendarView.setMaxDate(millis2);
```

and this is the xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.yahyazeid.testnotification.Jan"
    android:background="#cbbc9f">


<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:background="#cbbc9f"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Kindly add some code otherwise how can we figure out the problem.

Comment: @SohailZahid the code is XML containing only a calendar View, but when running the layout it still show the picture i deleted , i tried on different devices

Comment: Try clean > Build and Run again. If you have instant run enabled. Close the application of device> clear it from recent apps and Run the App again..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya i just tried it, still the same

Comment: You may be setting other layout to your java. Share your `java` and `xml` files.

Comment: @jankigadhiya no, because i changed the title from the java code, and it was changed successfully to the same layout

Answer (score 0):

If you design the layout for multiscreen support, then check the layout changes in respective resolution emulator.

Answer (score 0):

it was the `setContentView` problem.

As you can see above the activity is `Jan.class` and the `layout` of the class should be `activity_jan` , so mistakenly i typed it `activiy_feb`, so it was always opening the wrong `activity`.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_jan);
```

thanks all for the support